# How to do thermal analysis of a P channel high side drive circuit.

Tags: fet

I have to design a PCB where one of the features is such that every time a stepper motor is moving a fan switches on. A high side P channel FET driver has been suggested as shown below:

[image]

I just need to know what kind of heat this switch will be producing. I know it will only be very small given that FETs are low power devices but I am struggling with this basic theory a bit. It doesn't say what the drain to source resistance (Rds) is for when Vgs is -12 V it only gives to for when Vgs is -10V and -4.5V.

None of the graphs give this information either. I figured that if I knew Rds on for Vgs=-12V I could calculate the power dissipated across the FET (If i can also find the drain current at this value as well) and thus find the temperature at the junction using the thermal resistance of the part (159 degrees celcius per watt).

I am just very inexperienced at reading data sheets and would appreciate it if someone with more experience could push me in the right direction.

https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2307L.pdf[2](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2307L.pdf)

Thanks,

Simon.

Comment: How much current does the fan draw?

Comment: Notice Rds is a little lower at -10V than in is at -4.5V, but (normally) not radically different. Just use the -10V figure. (And if that indicates you need heatsinking, add heatsinking).

Comment: P=I^2*RdsON. Please note that RdsON increases with temperature. You will find it in the datasheet.

Comment: Unless you are switching, I2R losses will be small because of Lower Rdson.